# How do I keep the bottom part of the android app fixed while I switch activities like Instagram

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to create an App like Instagram as part of a project and I want to keep the bottom part of the app fixed with the different Image Buttons that takes you to different parts of the App like home, messages and other functionalities.

I am currently making my app in a Relative Layout and will be switching to Constraint Layout after I get my App properly developed

I want the bottom part of the App with the Image Buttons fixed when a user clicks one of those buttons and is taken to some other type of layout xml file

Comment: You can use BottomNavigation and Fragment for differents parts of App Like Home, Message etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about [Bottom navigation bars](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html) :

> Bottom navigation bars display three to five destinations at the bottom of a screen. Each destination is represented by an icon and an optional text label. When a bottom navigation icon is tapped, the user is taken to the top-level navigation destination associated with that icon.

[image]

With the Bottom navigation bars, you can switch fragments and have the navigation bar visible and fixed all over your app.

You can find a lot of information about how to create this, you can check [this toturial](https://medium.com/@suragch/how-to-add-a-bottom-navigation-bar-in-android-958ed728ef6c), [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ma5zAs3s0_8) and many more.

Comment: And how do I change the image of those icons everytime it is clicked

Comment: I belive that it is mentioned in tye toturial

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bottom Navigation View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) or even a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout) anchored at the bottom of an activity.

You need an Activity that will host Fragments. These fragments will be displayed in turn as you interact with the Activity's hosting view.

I have created an [Android Project](https://github.com/tendaimaswaya/BottomNavigationProject) to demonstrate. Sorry, you didn't specify language so i wrote it in Kotlin

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setupViewPager(pager)
    }
//the ViewPager will be responsible for navigating through your fragments even when you need to slide through them
    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager){
        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        setTabs(adapter)
       // viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        initTabLayout()
    }
    //assign icons to the TabLayout
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun setTabIcons(){
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0)!!.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext,R.mipmap.ic_launcher))

        tabLayout.getTabAt(1)!!.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext,R.mipmap.ic_launcher))

        tabLayout.getTabAt(2)!!.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext,R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    fun initTabLayout(){
        tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(pager)
        setTabIcons()

    }

//assign Fragments associated with a specific Tab Item
    private fun setTabs(adapter:ViewPagerAdapter){
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentOne(), "")
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentTwo(), "")
        adapter.addFragment(FragmentThree(), "")
    }
}

class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager){
private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return mFragmentList[position]
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return mFragmentList.size
}

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment)
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
}

override fun getPageTitle(position:Int): CharSequence{
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position)
}

}
```

Your single fragment will look something like:

```
class FragmentOne : Fragment() {
lateinit var rootView:View
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view,container,false)
    rootView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView).setText("Fragment One")
    return rootView
}
}
```

Your view will look something like this (in this case it is named fragment_view.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/container"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
         tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabPaddingStart="35dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="35dp"
        app:tabBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
/>
```